# KeyCode for text area keypressed event appcelerator titanium

Tags: ios, textarea, appcelerator, keycode

I am trying to find out the keycode,by using the keypressed  event of the textarea.but keypressed event is not working
an iphone please help me any other alternatives to find the keycode.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextArea-event-keypressed) you see there is indeed a `keypressed` event, but this is only for Android and Windows Phone.

For iOS you will have to use the `change` event: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextArea-event-change

Once this is fired, you get the value from the textArea, `$.textArea.value` (if your textarea ID is `textArea`) and you get the last character.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to specifically detect backspace press event when the textfield is empty???

Comment: @MuhammadQasim thats a completely different question. Please ask in a new question!